# Do half integer spin fields commute or anti-commute with spin integer fields?

Tags: fermions, commutator, grassmann-numbers, spin-statistics, anticommutator

What are the fundamental commutation/anti-commutation relations between half integer and integer spin fields? For instance, in QED do we have
\begin{equation}
[\psi(x),A^{\mu}(y)]=0
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
\lbrace\psi(x),A^{\mu}(y)\rbrace=0
\end{equation}
?

Comment: Related (duplicate?): https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235589/ In particular, though the question isn't exactly the same, the first answer seems to address yours.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They commute; see e.g. [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmann_number#General_description_and_properties) discussion of the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ grading involved.

Comment: Specific references where OP can read about Grassmann grading would make this answer much more helpful. Since googling "Grassmann grading" gives only 226 results and it appears to be mostly research papers and conference proceedings. ;)

Comment: @Chris Hopefully the latest edit helps more.