# What is the QFT state with two distinguishable fermions present?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, hilbert-space, fermions, commutator, anticommutator

I want to describe a system with two non-interacting and definitely different fermions, say an electron neutrino, $\nu_e$, and an electron, $e^-$.

The state describing a single electron is given using the Dirac creation operator
$$c^\dagger_e|0\rangle$$
where $|0\rangle$ is the vacuum state.

Similarly the state describing a single neutrino is
$$c_\nu^\dagger|0\rangle$$

My question is what is the state with both fermions present?  Is it simply
$$c^\dagger_ec^\dagger_\nu|0\rangle$$
If so, does it matter which way around the two creation operators are?  If not, surely that means different fermion operators **commute**, since I could have just as well have chosen to write
$$c^\dagger_\nu c^\dagger_e|0\rangle$$
Other questions on this topic (e.g. [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235589/)) suggest to me that they should **anticommute**, and in general I've come to believe that the whole point of these operators and what makes them so special is they anticommute with just about anything.

Comment: Yes, they anticommute.

Comment: In response to the edited question: yes, they anticommute. This is not only not weird, but also completely necessary to get correct results, e.g. see my answer [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/360206/why-do-we-antisymmetrize-the-baryons-wavefunction-but-not-the-mesons/376695#376695).

Comment: You can define the state with two fermions present as either $c_e^\dagger c_\nu^\dagger |0 \rangle$ or $c_\nu^\dagger c_e^\dagger |0 \rangle$, but the two definitions will differ by a minus sign. To avoid sign errors, you need to check what convention your source uses.

Comment: "...they anticommute with just about anything."  Not quite. All fermion creation operators anticommute with each other, but they commute with boson creation operators.