# Normal-Ordering of operators of two different types of fermions

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions

The normal-ordering of creation and annihilation operators is defined such that the creation operators are put to the left, with a minus sign for each permutation of two operators necessary to do this. In my case, I have a system of two different types of fermions (positrons and electrons) and I have creation and annihilation operators for positrons (I will call them $a^{\dagger}$ and $a$) and creation and annihilation operators for electrons ($b^{\dagger}$ and $b$). How is defined the normal-ordering in this case? For example, How can I compute $N(a_{i}^{\dagger} b_{j} a_{k} a_{l}^{\dagger})$?

My problem is that I think in this case the normal-ordering will be defined such that the creation operator (for positrons and electrons) are put to the left, but with a minus sign every time we permute two positrons or two electrons operators, that is, the permutation of one positron and one electron operators doesn't affect the sign. For example, $N(a_{i} b_{j} b_{k}^{\dagger}) = - b_{k}^{\dagger} a_{i} b_{j}$. Is it really correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fermions, different species and (anti-)commutation rules](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235589/)

Comment: I don't know if it's a duplicate, this question dosen't talk about normal-ordering, but it helped me with the anticommutations, so thanks!