# Swap fermion with boson?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, bosons, grassmann-numbers

I wonder what actions/factors/terms show up when you swap a fermion and boson that are tensored together in second quantisation. It would suffice for me if someone could give me the name of such an operation so I can search for it.

Nearly all sources only shows the case when there are only fermions or only bosons. Have only found a toy model (in that model there were no extra terms and the factor was 1 so swapping a fermion with boson was symmetric, but I don't know if this is true in general)

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235589/2451 and links therein.