# Propagator for Dirac spinor field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, greens-functions, propagator, anticommutator

I am currently trying to learn Quantum Field Theory through [David Tong's notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/qft.html) which only talk about canonical quantisation for the scalar field and Dirac spinor field.

In Chapter 2, the *propagator* for a *real scalar field* is defined as (and I believe this definition is standard since it is also the one used by Peskin and Schroeder):

$$
D(x-y) = \langle 0 | \phi(x)\phi(y) | 0 \rangle
$$

However, in Chapter 5, when we are quantising the Dirac spinor field, the propagator, $S_{\alpha\beta}$, is defined as

$$
i S _ { \alpha \beta } = \left\{ \psi _ { \alpha } ( x ) , \bar { \psi } _ { \beta } ( y ) \right\}
$$

This definition is also used in [Ben Allanach's Lectures](https://dec41.user.srcf.net/notes/III_M/quantum_field_theory.pdf) (notes taken by Dexter, see page 83).

However, this looks rather strange since the analogous thing to define would be something like
$$
S_{\alpha\beta} = \langle 0 | \psi_\alpha(x)\bar{\psi}_\beta(y) | 0 \rangle
$$

which should **not** be the anti-commutator.

Further down the Chapter, the Feynman propagator is defined in an analogous way to the Feynman propagator for the real scalar field as

$$
S _ { F } ( x - y ) = \langle 0 | T \psi ( x ) \bar { \psi } ( y ) | 0 \rangle \equiv \left\{ \begin{array} { c c } { \langle 0 | \psi ( x ) \bar { \psi } ( y ) | 0 \rangle } & { x ^ { 0 } > y ^ { 0 } } \\ { \langle 0 | - \bar { \psi } ( y ) \psi ( x ) | 0 \rangle } & { y ^ { 0 } > x ^ { 0 } } \end{array} \right.
$$

Hence, if $\langle 0 | \psi_\alpha(x)\bar{\psi}_\beta(y) | 0 \rangle$ is not a propagator, then does it represent anything meaningful? And why is it not the correct propagator definition?

PS: [This link](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/388620/) might be helpful but does not discuss what the object $\langle 0 | \psi_\alpha(x)\bar{\psi}_\beta(y) | 0 \rangle$ might potentially be and why it does not work as the propagator definition.

Comment: I don't know why Tong call the anticommutator a "propagator."  It's surely not standard language. I've always called it the "(anti) commutator function"

Comment: I think that we need compare complex scalar field and Dirac fermion

Comment: @mikestone That would have been a much better name for it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Notation (and concepts) in QFT tends to be very subtle.

#### Propagators

> A propagator is defined as the probability amplitude of annihilate at
>   event $y$ a particle created at event $x$.

Since a particle is created out from thin air, and the set up return to "nothing" when the particle is annihilated, its definition **always** requires an IN and OUT state! In particular, something *sandwich*ed by the vacuum, e.g.

$$\left< \Omega|\phi(y) \bar{\phi}(x) | \Omega \right>.$$

In the same foot, the for a fermion the propagator should be something like,

$$\left< \Omega|\psi(y) \bar{\psi}(x) | \Omega \right>.$$

However, there are several types of propagators one might define: retarded, advanced, Feynman, etc. But, the bottom line is that all of these are sandwich by the same IN and OUT state.

#### (micro) Causality

> Causality ensures that axioms from special relativity are valid.

Being that fundamental, causality should be preserved regardless of the IN and OUT states!

Causality is *measured* by the (anti)commutator of the fields, i.e. $[\phi(y),\bar{\phi}(x)]$ for bosons and $\{\psi(y),\bar{\psi}(x)\}$ for fermions.

$$[\phi(y),\bar{\phi}(x)] = 0 \quad \text{for }(x - y) \text{ spacelike}$$
$$\{\psi(y),\bar{\psi}(x)\} = 0 \quad \text{for }(x - y) \text{ spacelike}$$

### Why the confusion?

```
Love and marriage, love and marriage
They go together like a horse and carriage
Dad was told by mother
You can't have one without the other

--- Frank Sinatra
```

Because they are related! I recommend an *old fashion* classic by Wolfgang Pauli "*Selected Topics in Field Quantization*".

The micro causality condition is not *imposed* as stated above, but usually only the weaker conditions below are required:

$$\left<\Omega|[\phi(y),\bar{\phi}(x)]|\Omega\right> = 0 \quad \text{for }(x - y) \text{ spacelike}$$
$$\left<\Omega|\{\psi(y),\bar{\psi}(x)\}|\Omega\right> = 0 \quad \text{for }(x - y) \text{ spacelike}$$

Answer (score 1):

For Dirac spinor field:

$$
i S _ { \alpha \beta }(x-y) = \left\{ \psi _ { \alpha } ( x ) , \bar { \psi } _ { \beta } ( y ) \right\}
=
\langle 0 | \psi_\alpha(x)\bar{\psi}_\beta(y) | 0 \rangle
+
\langle 0 | \bar{\psi}_\beta(y)\psi_\alpha(x) | 0 \rangle
$$

$$
(\gamma^\mu\partial_\mu + m)\langle 0 | \psi_\alpha(x)\bar{\psi}_\beta(y) | 0 \rangle =0
$$

For complex scalar field $\phi$:

$$
i\Delta(x-y)
=
[\phi(x),\bar{\phi}(y) ]
=
\langle 0 | \phi(x)\bar{\phi}(y) | 0 \rangle
-
\langle 0 | \bar{\phi}(y)\phi(x) | 0 \rangle
$$

$$
(\partial^2 + m^2)\langle 0 | \phi(x)\bar{\phi}(y) | 0 \rangle
=0
$$

So there is some analogy between complex scalar and Dirac field. In Feynman propogator you need to add $\theta$-functions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, if I recall correctly, $\Delta(x-y)$ is not the *propagator* for complex scalar field $\phi$ because the propagator is denoted by $D(x-y)$ (correct me if I am wrong). But in this case $S_{\alpha\beta}$ is *defined* as the propagator which will break the analogy.

Comment: How do you define propogator for complex scalar field?

Comment: I have not come across such a definition in my notes. I only know how to define the Feynman propagator for complex scalar field but obviously that is a different object