# Anticommutator Relation of Quantized Fermionic Field and Fermi–Dirac statistics: How are these related?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, fermions, second-quantization, spin-statistics, anticommutator

I'm reading the Wikipedia article about [Fermionic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermionic_field#Dirac_fields) and have some troubles to understand the meaning following phrase:

> We impose an anticommutator relation (as opposed to a commutation relation as we do for the bosonic field) in order to make the operators compatible with Fermi–Dirac statistics.

I understand that the (anti)commutator relations for operatorys are posed as algebraic conditions in the operator algebra with "composition" as binary relation there. So up to now that's a purely "algebraic data".

But what does it mean that the operators should be compatible with [Fermi–Dirac statistics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%E2%80%93Dirac_statistics)? Compatible in which sense? I not understand in what is the concrete connection between the obtained the operators obtained from second quantization procedure and the Fermi–Dirac statistic, in mathematical terms a distribution. How these concepts fit together?

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 2):

My understanding is that the anticommutator relationship shows that the many-particle wave function is asymmetric relative to particle exchange, which is related to the Pauli exclusion principle and also half-integer spin, which, in turn, defines Fermi-Dirac statistic, where the maximal value can't exceed one, unlike in the case of the Bose-Einstein statistics.

The spin statistic theorem talks about this, you can find it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin%E2%80%93statistics_theorem).

To answer your question, they are compatible in the sense that two particles can't occupy the same quantum state.

Comment: I'm not completely sure if I understand you first statement correctly. Say we start with a many-particle wave function and want to turn it into an operator via second quantization. At this stage we a priori "don't know yet" from naive point of view, if we should impose commutator or anticommutator rule. Should your statement be read as that *if* we would be "somehow" able to figure out, that the only possible relation we can impose for the quantized field must be anticommutative,

Comment: then we would be able to deduce that the wave function we initially started with should have been asymmetric wrt particle exchange? Do I understand your statement correctly?

Comment: If many many-particle wave function of indistinguishable particles is given (you say you start with it), it possesses certain symmetry relative to particle exchange in it. This will affect the commutation rules for the second-quantization operators.

Comment: In other words, to build a many-body theory of particles you need to know what those particles are in terms of spin and mass and how they interact.

Comment: You may ask why particles with half-spin have to have asymmetrical wave function relative to particle exchange, but this is another question. It has something to do with the phase of the wave function and rotations I believe. What we have established here is the commutator rules are governed by the symmetry of the wave function relative to particle exchange and also this symmetry defines what statistics should be.

Comment: So far I know the "why particles with half-spin have to have asymmetrical wave function relative to particle exchange" part is exactly the of spin-statistic theorem I'm familar with. So that's not the issue of my concern. The point which I still not understood is, say we start with some many-particle wave function and want to perform second quantization on it. As you said it posses as a honest function certain symmetries relative to particle exchange, which we a priori know, since this function is given. Now the funny question is why these symmetries on level of this wave function "dictate"

Comment: to us which bracket relation we should take for associated creation/annihilation op's? In other words why we would obtain something absurd if we would try to assign naively just any random (only formally mathematically meaningful) bracket relation coming into mind , ie under "ignoring" the given symmetries relative to particle exchange our wave function have. Where in the construction something breakes badly down if we would try to do our quantization it that way? (my motivation is if it's possible to refute this suggested "approach" by certain reductio ad adsurdum argument)