# Question about a construction of a 1+1 free Dirac field

Tags: field-theory, fermions, dirac-equation

I have a question about the example Ron Maimon gave [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17926)  of a (1+1) dimensional free Dirac field. In the original wording:

> In two dimensions (one space one time), there is a nice dimensionally reduced analog, which is the right-moving (necessarily massless) Majorana-Weyl Fermion (the argument also works with 2d Dirac fermions with two components, but this is the simplest case).

Question: Why we can draw at that stage the conclusion that this field should necessarily be massless, ie where does it precisely follow from?

Comment: How would you suggest to write down a mass term for a Majorana-Weyl fermion?

Comment: @ACuriousMind: I see that it "is difficult" to realize :) At least up to now my attempts failed. But can it by an abstract argument be showed by assuming which abstract properties such MW fermion hypothetically would have, that it's not possible (ie via reductio ad absurdum), or is it a "contemporary consens" that it cannot have mass since nobody constructed it up to now

Comment: @ACuriousMind: ups, it seems that it was simpler then I thought; a Weyl fermion must be just from it's definition be massless, so the quoted statement is just tautological one