Proof that commuting Dirac fields violate causality
What is the proof that commuting Dirac fields violate causality? All sources I could find just quote this result, but I couldn't find an explicit derivation anywhere. In particular, the case I am considering is where the fermionic ladder operators commute, and then, such that this does not result in negative energies in the time-ordered Hamiltonian, the free Dirac field expression is (incorrectly) modified to be $$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p})} \sum_{s=1,2} [b(s,\vec{p})u(s,{\vec{p}})e^{-ik\cdot x} + d(s,\vec{p})v(s,\vec{p})e^{ik\cdot x}]$$
instead of the usual, causality-preserving expression $$\psi(x) = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p})} \sum_{s=1,2} [b(s,\vec{p})u(s,\vec{p})e^{-ik\cdot x} + d^{\dagger}(s,\vec{p})v(s,\vec{p})e^{ik\cdot x}]$$.
I am trying to show that for the first expression, the commutator $[\psi(x) , \bar{\psi}(x) ]$ would not vanish for space-like separated intervals $(x-y)$, thereby violating causality. These are my steps: Using the (acausal) ladder commutators $[b(s,\vec{p}),b^{\dagger}(r,\vec{q})] = [d(s,\vec{p}),d^{\dagger}(r,\vec{q})] = (2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p}) \delta (\vec{p}-\vec{q}) \delta_{rs}$ we get
$$[\psi(x) , \bar{\psi}(x) ] = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p} d^3 \vec{q}}{(2\pi)^6 4E(\vec{p})E(\vec{q})} \sum_{r,s=1,2} ( [b(s,\vec{p}),b^{\dagger} (r,\vec{q})] e^{ -i (p \cdot x - q \cdot y)} + [d(s,\vec{p}),d^{\dagger} (r,\vec{q})] e^{ i (p \cdot x - q \cdot y)} ) $$. Applying these commutators and using spinor summation formulae, for on-shell energies this gives:
$$[\psi(x) , \bar{\psi}(x) ] = \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p})} [e^{ -i p \cdot (x - y)} (\not{p} + m) + e^{ i p \cdot (x - y)} (\not{p} + m) ]$$
$$[\psi(x) , \bar{\psi}(x) ] = (i\not{\partial}_{x} + m) \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p})} [e^{ -i p \cdot (x - y)} - e^{ i p \cdot (x - y)} ]$$
However, the expression $[e^{ -i p \cdot (x - y)} - e^{ i p \cdot (x - y)} ]$ does vanish for space-like separated intervals. The correct expression should be $$[\psi(x) , \bar{\psi}(x) ] = (i\not{\partial}_{x} + m) \int \frac{d^3 \vec{p}}{(2\pi)^3 2E(\vec{p})} [e^{ -i p \cdot (x - y)} + e^{ i p \cdot (x - y)} ]$$ such that commutation of Dirac fields can be shown to violate causality. It seems that my proof follows the same steps as the proof that anticommuting Dirac fields abide by causality, as my steps do not use any of the commutator properties. What are the correct steps to take in order to prove this result?

Possible duplicates: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/17893/2451 and links therein.
